# No file was submitted. Check the encoding type on the form

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

below shows my example project. but it raise an error while submitting. i've added enctype to form field . but no way. please help :)

**html**

```
<form class="forms2" action="." method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">{%csrf_token%}
            <fieldset>
              <ol>

                   {% for field in forms %}
                   <li class="form-row">

                  <b>{{ field.label_tag }}</b> {{ field }} </li>
                  <i>{{ field.errors }}</i>


                  {%endfor%}



                  <li class="button-row">
                  <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" class="btn-submit" />
                </li>
              </ol>

              </fieldset>

                </form>
```

**forms.py**

```
class CarrerApplication(forms.Form):
    applicant_name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'text-input required'}),label='Name')
    applicant_address = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'text-input required'}),label='Address')
    applicant_email = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'text-input required email'}),label='Email')
    applicant_mobile = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'text-input'}),label='Mobile')
    applicant_resume = forms.FileField(widget=forms.FileInput(attrs={'name':'applicant_resume'}),label='Resume')
    applicant_message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'class':'text-area'}),label='Message')



    def clean_applicant_resume(self):
        applicant_resume = self.cleaned_data['applicant_resume']
        exts = ['doc', 'docx', 'pdf', 'jpg', 'png', 'xls', 'xlsx', '.xlsm', '.xlsb']
        max_email_attach_size = 10485760 #10MB written in bytes

        if not applicant_resume in (None, ''):

            try:
                if applicant_resume.size > max_email_attach_size:
                    raise ValidationError("The file is too big")

                file_extension = applicant_resume.name.split('.')[1]
                if file_extension not in exts:
                    raise ValidationError("Invalid File Type")

            except AttributeError:
                raise ValidationError(self.error_messages['invalid'])

        return applicant_resume
```

**views.py**

```
def careers(request):



   if request.method == 'POST':

      form = CarrerApplication(request.POST,request.FILES)
      if form.is_valid():

            applicant_name= request.POST.get('applicant_name')
            applicant_address=request.POST.get('applicant_address')
            applicant_mobile=request.POST.get('applicant_mobile')
            applicant_email=request.POST.get('applicant_email')
            applicant_resume=request.FILES.get('applicant_resume')
            applicant_message = request.POST.get('applicant_message')
            subject = 'Resume from Blaah blaah'
            email = 'anishmenon@me.com'

            message_template = loader.get_template('resume_mail/resume_send.txt')
            message_context = Context({ 'name': applicant_name,'message':applicant_message })
            message = message_template.render(message_context)
            mail = EmailMessage(subject, message, applicant_email, [email])

            mail.attach(applicant_resume.name, applicant_resume.read(), applicant_resume.content_type)
            mail.send()

            return HttpResponse('Thanks')
   else:
        form = CarrerApplication()

   return render_to_response('resume_mail/resume_apply.html',
                           {'forms' : form},
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

**i'm getting an error while submitting form**

> No file was submitted. Check the encoding type on the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to instantiate your form with `request.POST` and `request.FILES`.

```
form = CarrerApplication(request.POST, request.FILES)
```

For more information see the docs on [binding uploaded files to a form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#binding-uploaded-files-to-a-form).

Comment: Why is `applicant_mobile` a `FileField` if you are using a `TextInput` widget?

Comment: Typo, thnks for informing .

Answer (score 1):

It will be cool to do so

```
form = CarrerApplication((request.POST,request.FILES) or None)
if request.method == 'POST':
     .......
```

Comment: form = CarrerApplication(request.POST,request.FILES or None)

( is enough ) .

Answer (score 1):

I also get this problem, I change FileInput into ClearableFileInput.

```
applicant_resume = forms.FileField(widget=forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'name':'applicant_resume'}),label='Resume')
```

Comment: Just for clarification, was this your solution to your problem?